# favicon for my GWT webapp is not showing

Tags: java, gwt

I add a favicon.ico under my **war** directory but it is not showing up when the app is running in Development mode. Why? When I run the Mail sample app in Development mode, its favicon is shown correctly in Firefox.

Info: I'm using GWT version 2.0 in Eclipse galileo

Comment: browser cache ? broken favicon file?

Comment: I can view the favicon.ico in my file explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now. I deleted the file & redeployed another version of favicon.ico & it now appears in the FF browser bar.